# google apps engine django form pyamf

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-apps, pyamf

My flash-pyamf-gae works nice.
Now I would like to create a classic Django form by following the google tutorial : http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html
I did but when I post the data entered in my form i get the following message from pyamf :

> Malformed stream (amfVersion=110)
>
> 400 Bad Request The request body was
>   unable to be successfully decoded.
>
> Traceback:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Giil\Documents\dev\gae\moviesbuilder\pyamf\remoting\gateway\google.py",
>   line 79, in post
>       logger=self.logger, timezone_offset=timezone_offset)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Giil\Documents\dev\gae\moviesbuilder\pyamf\remoting_*init*_.py",
>   line 640, in decode
>       msg.amfVersion) DecodeError: Malformed stream (amfVersion=110)Malformed stream (amfVersion=110)

Now that make sens to me because what I send from my form is not amf. How can I deal with this ?

Note : I have the feeling that the problems come from my app.yaml
I have no special handler to tell the application to process this form differently...Malformed stream (amfVersion=110)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem my own way :

My Form (the post is directed towards another function and not just "/" as in google example) :

```
class Projects(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                '<form method="POST" '
                                'action="/ProjectsPage">'
                                '<table>')
        self.response.out.write(ProjectForm())
        self.response.out.write('</table>'
                                '<input type="submit">'
                                '</form></body></html>')
```

And then what I need to write to the dataStore and display the list :

```
class ProjectsPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
     #getting data and saving
     def post(self):
        data = ProjectForm(data=self.request.POST)
        if data.is_valid():
            # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
            entity = data.save(commit=False)
            entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
            entity.put()
            self.redirect('/projects.html')
        else:
            # Reprint the form
            self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                    '<form method="POST" '
                                    'action="/">'
                                    '<table>')
            self.response.out.write(data)
            self.response.out.write('</table>'
                                    '<input type="submit">'
                                    '</form></body></html>')
    #display list of projects
    def get(self):
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Project WHERE added_by=:1 ORDER BY name",users.get_current_user())
        template_values = {
            'projects': query,
        }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/projects.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```